# Is every regular (excellent) scheme separated?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes

Sorry for one more stupid AG question. I need schemes that are regular, excellent and separated. Are these three conditions independent?

Comment: Well, $\mathbb{A}^1 \cup_{\mathbb{A}^1-0} \mathbb{A}^1$ is smooth and non-separated. 

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**-** Separated, excellent, regular: Spec$(k)$.

**-** Separated, excellent, not regular: Spec$(k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2)$.

**-** Separated, not excellent, regular: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excellent_ring

**-** Separated, not excellent, not regular: Spec$(k[\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\ldots]/\langle\epsilon_1^2,\epsilon_2^2,\ldots\rangle$.

**-** Not separated, excellent, regular: Glue Spec$(\mathbb{Z})$ to itself along the complement of a closed point.

To get the other three, take the disjoint union of the fifth example with any of the second, third, or fourth examples.